# Windows Phone 8 Emulator - Not Working

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I run Win 8 Pro, with VS 2012 Ultimate and I installed Windows Phone 8 SDK. The Win 8 is installed directly on an SSD drive.
System details:
CPU: Intel i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
RAM: 32GB
Hyper-V installed and working fine (running some other instances, Dynamics, SharePoint) no problems at all.

This tool: https://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/ reports: You have a SLAT capable machine.

Using Intel Processor Identification Utility I get the following info: [image: http://i48.tinypic.com/2r79i7b.jpg]

However when i create a new windows phone 8 project, and start that application, the emulator show's "The Windows Phone OS is starting". It stays that way for few minutes after it closes. In Hyper-V the instance is running but the emulator is not working. I tried many cases, repair, uninstall, install, remove switches, recreate them ... nothing! The same result each time.

What might be the problem?

Is my machine compatible running virtualization? I guess yes because it works fine running some other virtual instances ...

Comment: P.S. No other virtualization software installed except Hyper-V

Comment: I think your virtualization capability is disabled, try to enable cupu virt from bios.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to run VM's? If you have the hyper-v hypervisor enabled in windows 8 then the intel processor identification program is reporting correctly. One new 'feature' in windows 8 is that when you enable the hyper-v functionality it treats EVERYTHING as a VM.

So when you are booting up your computer what you think is your physical machine running your physical windows 8 pro operating system is not so. What your computer is doing is booting up some hidden core program that acts as a hyper-v host and then boots your windows 8 pro operating system as a hyper-v client (with zero hardware virtualization).

From Microsofts point of view I can understand this makes their life easier with everything on the same playing field. But in this case when you go to run your WP8 VM it goes to use the hardware virtualization functions and finds out that they are not there and visual studio then can't use the full functionality it is expecting when you are attempting to debug your code in the virtual environment.